# Why can Avodah Zara be בטל בשישים?

Tags: talmud-gemara, halacha-theory, avodah-zarah, bitul-batel-null, masecheth-avodah-zarah

If עבודה זרה is so strict, why can it be בטל by 1/60 in דבר שלא במינו? (see [:עבודה זרה ע"ג](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.73b?lang=bi))

Comment: I do not see where the Gemara says that. Au contraire it says that  בטל by 1/60 applies to everywhere **except** עבודה זרה.

Comment: You mean yayin nesech?

Comment: IMSMC, an idolatrous offering is never batel and even its proceeds (and their proceeds, etc.) are forbidden. (Hence the recurring controversy regarding Hindu temple derived wigs.)